# permissons not behaving as intended after using acl

Tags: linux, rhel

hi  i have two groups named sales1 account1,two directories named sales1 account1 and below are the users

```
carolina:x:1006:
marcha:x:1007:
lori:x:1008:
boby:x:1009:
sales1:x:1010:carolina,marcha
account1:x:1011:lori,boby
```

and here are the acl applied on both sales1/ ,account1 directories

```
[root@localhost ~]# getfacl /home/data/sales1/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/data/sales1/
# owner: root
# group: sales1
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:account1:rw-
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:account1:rw-
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

and this what happen when i try to touch file to sales1/ from a user from account directory

```
[root@localhost ~]# su boby
[boby@localhost root]$ touch /home/data/sales1/file1
touch: cannot touch '/home/data/sales1/file1': Permission denied
[boby@localhost root]$ groups
boby account1
```

im so confused aren't rw- means i can read file and edit it ?!

Comment: Without x permission, you can't use touch. Touch will first check if the file you want to create exists already. It can't do that, because it can't search the directory without x. Perhaps x permissions are also required to create a file.

Comment: you are absolutely right it worked thanks